# Windows 8 - How to turn off USB connection sounds?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, usb

Windows 8 plays a sounds when you connect or disconnect a USB device. How can I turn that sounds off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your sound settings in Control panel -> Sound tab
Windows default sound should be the selected one. Then select No sound option and save.
I hope [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/285-sounds-change.html) would help you with some alternative options.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Control Panel.

Click on Sounds

Select the Sounds tab.

Search for the following events:

Device connect.

Device Disconnect.

Select "Device connect".

Click on the "Sounds" drop menu and select "None".

Click on Apply.

Repeat the operation for the "Device disconnect" event.